# Relative interior of a polytope

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology

Can anyone explain to me what is the idea of relative interior of a convex hull of a set of finite points ?
For interior of a set , I understand that it is a set which excludes its boundary. 
Is interior of a set a subset of relative interior of a set ?

Answer (score 1):

The **relative** interior refers to the fact, that you only consider the interior of set w.r.t. its affine hull.

Here is one example. Take a 3d point set, all points lie on a common plane $h$. The convex hull of this set is a "2d object" with affine hull is $h$. Its interior in $\mathbf{R}^3$ is $\emptyset$. The **relative** interior however is the convex hull without vertices and edges. In other words it is the interior w.r.t. the plane $h$.

Comment: So let's say I have two points and I take their affine hull. The relative interior of this two points is the set which contains the points on the affine hull of the two points, which is an edge ? Am I right ?

Comment: Do you mean you take the convex hull of the two points and consider then the relative interior? Otherwise it doesn't make sense. The relative interior of a finite union of singeltons will be empty.